# How can I find out what is teleporting in?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, teleportation

Let us say I can pinpoint the exact endpoint of a teleportation, e.g. with [Trace Teleport](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/trace-teleport). Is there any way to find out what is coming? In 3.5 there is the spell [Anticipate Teleportation](http://alcyius.com/dndtools/spells/complete-arcane--55/anticipate-teleportation--435/index.html) that at least gives the creature's size and how many creatures are coming, but I cannot find an equivalent in Pathfinder. Is there any way to know?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Is the site now okay with a *D&D Tools* link?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Missed that while I was editing. I think [my practical objection to them still applies](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/2773/321). (Ironically in this case though, the link going down doesn't risk robbing the post of any information because the spell name is already sufficient reference, so relative to that practical objection it's kinda six of one, half a dozen of the other whether it's left in or taken out.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Trace Teleport](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/trace-teleport) covers that already:

> Whenever you detect the origin point or **termination point** of any teleportation effect with this spell, you can study that origin point or termination point for 1 round. If you do, you can attempt a caster level check (DC = 11 + the teleportation effect's caster level), taking a –5 penalty if the effect occurred more than 1 minute ago. If you succeed, **you gain a glimpse of the** teleportation effect's termination point (if you detected an origin point) or **origin point (if you detected a termination point)**.

This means that you can see the origin point of this teleportation effect.

You do need a round for that, so [most](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dimension-door) [teleportation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/teleport) [spells](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/interplanetary-teleport) will be finished before you have time for that, since they are *instantaneous*, but that also means that you will immediately see what is coming out of the teleport.

For teleportation effects that take longer to finish their effects, like a [Gate](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/gate), [Getaway](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/getaway), or [Teleportation Circle](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/teleportation-circle), you can look at what is on the other side (the *origin*) of the spell effect.

The spell *anticipate teleportation* only worked on *willing creatures*, so it wasn't really great to know what and how many enemies are coming out of a teleportation effect, and it could anticipate because you had the option to delay the effect for a round.

As for *instantaneous* teleportation, your only option would be to use a [Divination](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/divination) (or similar) spell and anticipate that someone is going to teleport to your location.

Or to ask your GM to convert the *greater anticipate teleportation* spell from *D&D 3.5e* to *Pathfinder.*

Comment: The target of the spell *anticipate teleportation* is a willing creature; then the spell's effect affects all teleportation effects within its area, and *greater  anticipate teleportation* does exactly what the asker wants.

Comment: I don't think *trace teleport* works the way the answer makes it sound. First, the caster "can detect the lingering traces of any teleportation effect that occurred up to 1 hour previously, in the same fashion" as detecting a teleportation effect that's happens while the caster's in the area. Second, the *trace teleport* spell only reveals the teleportation effect's origin point, termination point, or both, not the creature that created the effect or the creatures that were subject to the effect, which is what the asker wants.

Comment: @HeyICanChan it works for spells that arent instantaneous, and i explained that it can see the other "side" of the effect. Nowhere i said it can see creatures, but it will see whoever is on the other side.

Comment: O, okay! So the spell *trace teleport* is no help *as the creature's arriving or departing* even though it could still be used after the creatures have arrived or departed. Got it. I'm still unsure if *trace teleport* lets the caster see at the origin or termination points things *other than* the point itself, though. That sounds like an expansion of the spell's mandate.

Comment: I believe that will depend on the GM, as this glimpse is defined as: "This glimpse lasts long enough for you to get a brief look at the area, but not long enough to scrutinize it in detail." To me, this means that you cannot use this glimpse as to get familiar with the location for a teleport, but you could remember it if you see it again. And since it says you take a brief look, anyone or anything on the location could be seen aswell.